# Are the files opened with the photos application of Windows 10 temporary stored anywhere?

Tags: windows-10, temporary-files, virtual-drive, windows-photo-viewer

I'm saving some designs in a virtual drive with an encryption software. When the virtual drive is off, sometimes the photos can still be opened by clicking them in recent files and they are opened in the photos application of Windows 10. Sometimes they dont appear, sometimes they appear for a second and disappear, and sometimes they are viewable like they just were there. Why is this so? Are the files opened with the photos application of Windows 10 temporary stored anywhere?

Comment: Any OS uses temporary folder or folders.

Comment: but any idea which temporary folder could in this case be using?

Comment: https://www.askvg.com/where-does-windows-store-temporary-files-and-how-to-change-temp-folder-location/

Answer (score 2):

We can just use keyboard hotkey `win` + `R` to run `Run`, then type `%temp%`, you can open the temporary files the current user have. Then you can see the picture you think it has been stored temporarily.

As I know, if you restart the machine, the temporary files will gone. And you can run the cleanup of the system disk.

Answer (score 2):

The photos app can be configured to show recent photos on the live tile, in this case a version of the file is copied to `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\PhotosAppTile`

If you're concerned about data security, metadata from files found is also stored in a SQLite file in the folder above